# Maven running cucumber specific feature files or folders

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How is it possible to use the cucumber feature option from maven **command line**.
Of a tree full of features (tests), I'm trying to run only individual features. In my case - all feature files in a selected folder.

I've tried to use the following syntax:

```
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="classpath:com/company/regression/features/administration/"
```

It runs all tests. No errors and no comments.
I tried several other options and none worked!

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I changed my approach, and decided to use tags instead.
Now, I run a command that tells me which tags to use and I make sure to put a special tag at the beginning of the feature file.
My command now looks like:

```
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @runThis --tags ~@ignore --format json-pretty:target/cucumber-report-myReport.json --format html:target/cucumber-html-report-myReport"
```

The tag I put is **@runThis** and the **~@ignore** is to tell cucumber **not** to run the **@ignore** tags.
I also create a different report for each run, so Jenkins cucumber plugin can create a single report from all the different runs and they don't overwrite each other.

I hope this helps.

Comment: While running from maven terminal I used the following command to achieve cucumber parallelism using Cucumber Parallel JVM plugin.
*mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke --tags @Regression"* but it failed to execute. ~[Didn't generate the Dynamic runner file itself]~
But executing with single tag is working
*mvn install -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"*
What could be the solution to over come this?