# Cucumber - How to run tags or feature files based on the pom/goal?

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have all my scenarios properly tagged and working.
I am trying to set it up so that depending on the goal that is set, only specific tags or feature files (whatever is possible) run.

I've looked at other related questions but didn't find one that seem to work for me.

I don't need to put anything conditional in as I've seen in a previous question that's not easily doable.

I did see in another question they found a way of doing it my making a Cucumber.Run super class and passing in the needed options then but there weren't further details.

And recommendations would be great.
I tried using various profiles/builds to exclude all but the desired feature file but Cucumber.Run seems to ignore that after my research.

To make it clear, basically I have:

```
File1.feature
@scenarioForFile1
----------------
File2.feature
@scenarioForFile2
----------------
File3.feature
@scenarioForFile3
```

And I need to control which set of tests is kicked of either by scenario or file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another day of research I was able to find the answer and feel stupid because I've looked at the usage docs several times but thought I couldn't do what the example showed in my use case.

Now I just have various build set up that run the project using different tags in the command line argument. I thought it was necessary to use the pom but it was not.

Used the below two links:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

[Maven running cucumber specific feature files or folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237753/maven-running-cucumber-specific-feature-files-or-folders)